# I have 2 tables pipe and leakage Pipe

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables pipe and leakage

```
Pipe(Pipe_object, Pipe_status, DIAMETER, MATERIAL, BBZ_LEVEL, SUR_REQ_DATE, PRESS_REG)

Leakage (Pipe_object,LEAKAGE_DATE, Job_No, Leak_Cause, Rep_Type)
```

I have to find the records where the leak_cause = 'ST' and sur_req_date is not null. currently below query is displaying the records which are having count <=2 (i.e it is displaying 3 pipe_objects if condition is specified to 2)

```
SELECT PI.PIPE_OBJECT, PI.PRESS_REG,PI.DIAMETER,PI.MATERIAL,PI.PIPE_STATUS, PI.BBZ_LEVEL,  LE.PIPE_OBJECT, LE.LEAKAGE_DATE 
  FROM PIPE PI JOIN LEAKAGE LE ON PI.PIPE_OBJECT = LE.PIPE_OBJECT 
  WHERE PI.MATERIAL = 'CI' AND  PI.SUR_REQ_DATE IS NOT NULL AND PI.PIPE_STATUS <> 'A' AND PRESS_REG = 'LP' 
  AND LE.LEAK_CAUSE = 'ST' AND BBZ_LEVEL IN ('1','2','3','4','5') AND PI.DIAMETER = 6 AND PI.LDZ_ID = 'SC' 
  GROUP BY  PI.PIPE_OBJECT,PI.PRESS_REG, PI.BBZ_LEVEL, LE.LEAK_CAUSE,  PI.PIPE_STATUS,LE.PIPE_OBJECT,
LE.LEAKAGE_DATE, PI.MATERIAL, PI.DIAMETER HAVING COUNT(LE.PIPE_OBJECT) <= 2;
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: I want query to display records which has count less than 2